# Lua gsub regex to replace multiple occurances of characters

Tags: lua

I am trying to modify my URL to be clean and friendly by removing more than one occurrence of specific characters

```
local function fix_url(str)
return str:gsub("[+/=]", {["+"] = "+", ["/"] = "/", ["="] = "="}) --Needs some regex to remove multiple occurances of characters
end
url = "///index.php????page====about&&&lol===you"
output = fix_url(url)
```

What I would like to achieve the output as is this :

```
"/index.php?page=about&lol=you"
```

But instead my output is this :

```
"///index.php????page====about&&&lol===you"
```

Is gsub the way i should be doing this ?

Comment: `url = url:gsub("([+/=&?])%1", "\0%0"):gsub("(.)%z%1", ""):gsub("%z(.)%1%1", "%1"):gsub("%z.", "")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see how to do this with one call to `gsub`. The code below does this by calling `gsub` once for each character:

```
url = "///index.php????page====about&&&lol===you"

function fix_url(s,C)
    for c in C:gmatch(".") do
        s=s:gsub(c.."+",c)
    end
    return s
end

print(fix_url(url,"+/=&?"))
```

Comment: Thank's it works wonderfully and is super easy to implement and add more characters to for what i require.

Comment: You just need to be careful with certain characters. For example, a dot cannot be used as it will match everything (.+). You should escape all punctuation characters. I would write it like so: `function fix_url(s,C)
  local m
  for c in C:gmatch('.') do
    m = c
    if m:match '%W' then m = '%'..m end
    s = s:gsub(m..'+',c)
  end
  return s
end
`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution (replace %p with whatever character class you like):

```
local
function fold(s)
  local ans = ''
  for s in s:gmatch '.' do
    if s ~= ans:sub(-1) then ans = ans .. s end
  end
  return ans
end

local
function fix_url(s)
  return s:gsub('%p+',fold) --remove multiple same characters
end

url = '///index.php????page====about&&&lol===you'
output = fix_url(url)

print(output)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks :) Both solutions provided worked fantastic but i marked the above as the answer due to it being easier to use for what i require <3